# Attach Link to Entire HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to attach a link to an HTML canvas, such that it is loaded on clicking anywhere in the canvas.

It seems like this should be a very simple problem, but I couldn't get it to work with an `<a>` tag. The only way I can think of doing it is to attach an event listener to the canvas in Javascript and then attach the link from there - however, I would rather a pure HTML solution if possible.

Comment: Why you want pure HTML solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<a>` tag works for me.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>
</a>
```